# How to use JavaScript socket.io-client library via socks5 proxy?

Tags: node.js, proxy, socket.io, socks

I haven't found anything in the documentation of socket.io about proxy.

But maybe is it possible to set proxy via some options settings?

Are there any workarounds to work this socket.io via socks5 proxy in Node?

Answer (score 0):

SocketIO does not support proxies out of the box. What you need is a custom http agent which tunnels through the proxy. Fortunately there is [socks-proxy-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socks-proxy-agent) for that. Here's a demo:

```js
const ProxyAgent = require('socks-proxy-agent')
const IO = require('socket.io-client')

// agent for a local socks5 proxy
const Agent = new ProxyAgent('socks5://127.0.0.1:9050')

// connect to domain.com via Agent
const SocketClient = IO('http://domain', {
    agent: Agent,
})

SocketClient.on('connect', ()=>{
    console.log('connected via proxy!')
})
```